# Stacking SVG's ontop of each other in a DIV

Tags: html, css, svg

I"m looking to stack these three images ontop of each other. I don't care if they're showing as they're animated and two will pop out horizontally from the side of each.

I however am getting an issue.

Please see attached photo:

[image: Container issues]

All three SVG's are contained within the below structure:

```
<ImageContainer>
  <MainIcon />
  <JobListingIcon />
  <SingularListing />
</ImageContainer>;
```

This is within a flex box:

```
const ImageContainer = styled.div`
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #636388;

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
`;
```

I don't understand why they're being shown this way, and I have tried to have all 3 SVG's positioned absolute, but nothing.

What's the way to stack these? It it not a flex box? Potentially something like a MUI grid?

Sorry!

Comment: `flex-direction: column;` maybe? Please edit your question with a working code example

Comment: Hi @MarioG8, Thanks for coming back to me mate. Unfortunately, it still does position them spaced out. I can't send an additional photo. Dou know a way to stack all elements ontop of each other? Google doesn't seem to show the best results

Answer (score 5):

The problem with a phrase like "on top of each other" is that it is ambiguous. Do you mean:

1. vertically arranged on the page, or
2. one covers the other

It sounds like you might mean the second one.  You can achieve that with absolute positioning.

```
parent    <-- make this "position: relative;"
   child  )     
   child  )  make either (or both) of these "position: absolute; top: 0;"
```

If those `child` elements are `<svg>` elements, then you'll also need to make them `display: block`, since SVGs are `display: inline-block` by default.

###### Demo

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

.svg-two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg class="svg-one" width="100" height="100">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="linen"/>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg-two" width="100" height="150">
     <rect x="20" y="0" width="60" height="150" fill="limegreen"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou Paul! This is it, incredibly helpful. I truly thankyou for the indepth example and explanation. All the best. Thanks a lot, honestly. I'm a bit of a learner right now so some aspects i'm getting used to. Can shoot you my discord if you want. But yes thankyou!